# javascript first() method not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my cloud code I want to retrieve the first object in my class called "Messages", but its not working.  The console.log isn't even showing up so i figure im calling the first() method wrong?

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Messages);
  query.first({

    success: function(results){

      console.log("The first object was retrieved");
      body.push(results.get("messageBody"));
      senderName.push(results.get("senderName"));
      senderId.push(results.get("senderId"));
      response.success(getUsers);   //getUsers is a function

    }, error: function(error){

      response.error("Error");

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `Parse.Messages` when it's not a built-in class. Since it's your own class, then you'd use `"Messages"`.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Messages");
```